# MySQL - Grab 3 photo records for each blog article record

Tags: mysql, sql

As title reads, I would like to list all my blog articles showing 3 photos with each article. Not every article has photos.

**Example Result**

[image]

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.content, a.published, t.topic_title, au.firstname, au.lastname,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(p.photo_id,CHAR(8)) ORDER BY p.photo_id ASC SEPARATOR ';') AS photos
FROM blog_articles a
LEFT JOIN photos p USING (article_id)
LEFT JOIN blog_topics t ON a.topic_id = t.topic_id
LEFT JOIN admins au ON a.author_id = au.admin_id
GROUP BY a.article_id
```

Which produces a colon delimited list of photo ID's, like I wanted, but I really only need 3, not all of them. Obviously I can just grab 3 ID's in my application code, but I would like to stop collecting all that data in MySQL. This is what it produces:

```
14   This is a blog title   2012-07-09    12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25
```

But all I want is:

```
14   This is a blog title   2012-07-09    12;13;14
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend your group_concat with [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONVERT(p.photo_id,CHAR(8)) 
        ORDER BY p.photo_id ASC 
        SEPARATOR ';'
    ),
    ';',
    3
) AS photos
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Let's say one article has 100 photos. Does this actually stop all 100 id's being produced, or does it cut the 100 to 3?

Comment: its concat all 100 to one string and then cut the string at the 3th `;`, so the result contains max 3 ids